# Empty MSI property after adding value

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Is there any special handling required when setting a property through a CustomAction provided by a merge module? I have two custom actions providing three properties to be used later within the merge module. They are set by usual C# code:

```
session["APPSRVPORT"] = port.ToString();
```

MSI log reports that the property has been set to a value:

```
MSI (s) (C0!DC) [11:58:04:615]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding APPSRVPORT property. Its value is '11376'.
```

When it comes to install the components, the following statement is used to install a registry value which uses the MSI property filled above:

```
<RegistryValue Name="AppSrvPort" Value="[APPSRVPORT]" Type="string" />
```

However, the log shows that the value is empty at this point:

```
MSI (s) (C0:AC) [11:58:06:208]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=AppSrvPort,,)
```

Can anybody tell me how to fix this? I've already checked, that the execute sequence is valid (i.e. setting the property comes before action "WriteRegistryValues")

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you confirm the custom action is immediate, and is in fact scheduled before WriteRegistryValues (per sequence numbers in the table, not just positions in the log)? (It's also a bit weird to set a non-builtin property that lacks a guid suffix in a merge module, but that's not the problem here.)

Answer (score 2):

When you reference a property in a .wxs script of a merge module, it will be **modularized** (i.e. having the merge module GUID appended). So the `<RegistryValue>` element will actually be interpreted like this:

```
<RegistryValue Name="AppSrvPort" Value="[APPSRVPORT.YOUR_MERGE_MODULE_ID]" Type="string" />
```

`YOUR_MERGE_MODULE_ID` will be the GUID of the merge module having `-` replaced by `_`, e. g. `1E35CFEB_7FA9_49F2_8E0D_5D941720EE81`.

To fix the issue, you could either **append the merge module ID when writing the property** or **suppress modularization**.

Since you are using the property only *within* the merge module, I'd suggest the former to avoid accidentally overwriting any existing property of the main MSI that has the same name. Think of the merge module ID as the "namespace":

```
session["APPSRVPORT.YOUR_MERGE_MODULE_ID"] = port.ToString();
```

Suppressing modularization can be useful if a property is **intended to be shared** between the main MSI and the merge module:

```
<Property Id="APPSRVPORT" SuppressModularization="yes"/>
```

Note: Suppressing modularization will issue warnings CNDL1006 and CNDL1086 which can be ignored, if you know what you are doing. ;-)

Comment: But does this apply to references of the property **within** the merge module, too? The property is used again by a component which is defined in the same merge module and is not shared between the merge module and the MSI itself.

Comment: @Marc Sorry I misread your question, but what I wrote still applies. The `<RegistryValue>` element will try to read the property with the merge module ID appended, unless you suppress modularization. You can verify that by opening the .MSM file using some tool (e.g. [InstEd](http://www.instedit.com/)) and look at the `Registry` table.